# Material UI Datagrid in an MUI Grid component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am attempting to put my MUI datagrids in an MUI grid. However, my grid items do not seem to be going into grid format at all (ie all the DataTables are in one area, none of them are siding next to each other even though they take up less than half the space each on the page).

Here is my sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-morning-gs58yh?file=/src/App.js

When the page is zoomed out or the side is widened, there is only one grid item per row.

Any thoughts or advice?

Comment: Hi Christina, are you able to create a minimal, reproducible example? I'd love to play around with this code myself and see what's going on.

Comment: My guess is that you're using flex direction of column which creates rows

Comment: So sorry, I took the day off after 7pm. I will upload one soon, hopefully, if I cannot figure it out myself

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-morning-gs58yh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This looks fine to me, not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. On wider screens you want the cards to wrap next to each other?

Comment: I want the cards to wrap next to each other on wider screens!

Comment: [Temporary Vanilla CSS Fix](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-sammet-glyvbj) While I figure out how Material UI works

Comment: I actually cannot find a way to do this in MUI, no wonder you're having trouble with it

Comment: Haha T.T might have to try for tailwind UI or another grid. I'll open a git issue for now as well

Comment: Happy to use the vanilla js you have above as well, thank youy so much!